# Elasticsearch Error : BindTransportException[Failed to bind to [9300-9400]

Tags: elasticsearch, centos, ip, host

I have installed elasticsearch latest version 5.5 on my CentOS server. In order to change the IP address, I have added the below lines in elasticsearch.yml file:

```
network.host = xyz.xyz.xy.xy (My Centos IP address)
http.port: 9200
```

When I start my elasticsearch, I am getting the below errors:

```
[2017-08-02T12:26:08,667][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: BindTransportException[Failed to bind to [9300-9400]]; nested: BindException[Cannot assign requested address];
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:114) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:67) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:122) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.BindTransportException: Failed to bind to [9300-9400]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.bindToPort(TcpTransport.java:793) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.bindServer(TcpTransport.java:758) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.doStart(Netty4Transport.java:173) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:69) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:209) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:69) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.start(Node.java:692) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:277) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:360) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:123) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:128) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:554) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1258) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:980) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:250) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:365) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_141]
```

I am able to start elasticsearch without editing my elasticsearch.yml. But I have to access elasticsearch outside of my centos machine. Is there any other setting that I should change to make it work. Any help is appreciated

Comment: please provide the full exception stack trace, you cut it off after 80 chars, but this also lost information

Comment: I have updated my question with full errors please check

Answer (score 2):

Is is possible that are you trying to bind to an IP address to listen on via the `network.host` or `bind.host` parameters, that does not exist on this system?

Can you share the output of `ip addr list` and your elasticsearch.yml file (you can just use `grep "^[^#]" elasticsearch.yml` to ignore comments.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. It vanished after following [Unable to bind elasticsearch transport service to external interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47939234/unable-to-bind-elasticsearch-transport-service-to-external-interface?rq=1).

Newer elasticsearch versions distinguish between *development mode* and *production mode*. If you define any non-loopback IP (i.e. most probably anything else than 127.0.0.1) there will be some tests. From the logs:

> ... bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks 
>    ... node validation exception
>    [1] bootstrap checks failed
>    [1]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured

So, if you need a non-loopback IP, e.g. define in elasticsearch.yml:

`node.name: $myNodeName 
cluster.initial_master_nodes : $myNodeName`

and restart again.