# Unable to bind elasticsearch transport service to external interface

Tags: elasticsearch, networking, centos, cluster-computing, elastic-stack

I am trying to setup elasticsearch cluster with 2 virtual machines. I am not able to configure the cluster transport service with an external interface. I could able to use localhost:9300 as transport service, but I cannot use localhost URL to join the cluster. It is throwing an error when I use external interface name/IP to configure the cluster.

```
[2017-12-22T06:58:56,979][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [node-1] publish_address {10.0.1.33:9300}, bound_addresses {10.0.1.33:9300}
[2017-12-22T06:58:56,997][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [node-1] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2017-12-22T06:58:57,002][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [node-1] node validation exception
[2] bootstrap checks failed
```

My configuration:

```
cluster.name: ProductionCluster
node.name: node-1
network.host: 10.0.1.33
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.0.1.33","10.0.1.34"]
bootstrap.system_call_filter: false
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
```

> Elasticsearch Version: 6.1

Comment: If you configure an external interface, you're considered to be in "production mode" and [bootstrap checks are automatically enforced](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html#_development_vs_production_mode). Can you show which bootstrap checks are failing?

Comment: 2017-12-22T06:58:56,997][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [node-1] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2017-12-22T06:58:57,002][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [node-2] node validation exception
[1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max number of threads [2048] for user [elasticsearch] is too low, increase to at least [4096]

Comment: Above is the error what I am getting when I configure elasticsearch as production mode.

Comment: There you go then: `max number of threads [2048] for user [elasticsearch] is too low, increase to at least [4096]`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/max-number-threads-check.html

Comment: Thanks, @Val. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you configure an external interface, you're considered to be in "production mode" and [bootstrap checks are automatically enforced](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html#_development_vs_production_mode). Can you show which bootstrap checks are failing?

The error mentions that the `max number of threads [2048] for user [elasticsearch] is too low` and you need to `increase to at least [4096]`

You can find how to do it here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/max-number-threads-check.html